# HTMl5 rotating sprite towards mouse coords

Tags: javascript, html, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a sprite towards mouse position, but I just fail at figuring out the proper way to to calculate the angle. The ship is always facing wrong direction.

```
angle = Math.atan2( ship_coords[0] - e.clientX ,ship_coords[1] -  e.clientY  );
```

Please see the below example:

```js
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
 
 var ship = new Image();
 var ship_coords = [c.width/2, c.height/2]
 
 ship.onload = function(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
 }
 
 ship.src = "http://pixeljoint.com/files/icons/spaceship.png";
 
 var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180; 
 var angle = 0;
 
 c.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  angle = Math.atan2( ship_coords[0] - e.clientX ,ship_coords[1] -  e.clientY  );
 })
 

 function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect( 0,0,c.width,c.height );
  ctx.save(); 
  ctx.translate( ship_coords[0], ship_coords[1] ); //// align to center ///
  ctx.rotate( angle );
  ctx.drawImage( ship, -(ship.width/2), -(ship.height/2) ); //// set center of the image ////
  ctx.restore();
  window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
   #myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 578px;
  height: 200px;
   }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to invert the arithmetic.

Comment: My first though, nah it couldn't be that easy. But it indeed is :D.. thanks! :]